# Keep the selected option saved within js

Tags: javascript

Hey guys am new to javascript.I have a radio button check option with html..The code i have done

```
<form action="" id="avi">
<input type="radio" name="sex" value="male">Male<br>
<input type="radio" name="sex" value="female">Female
</form>
<br></br>

<button type="button"  id="bae">save me   </button>

<script>

var c = document.getElementById('bae');
c.onclick = function() {
var m = document.getElementById('avi'); 
return m.checked;
}
</script>
```

## what i need to do

The thing which i need to do is when i click the `save me button`  i just need to save the position of the clicked radio...Suppose if i clicked Male option and clicked save i need to see those clicked radio option after a refresh..

Can this be done without storing in db ??..I think this could be done with js..

Thanksfor the help

Comment: You could save it in a cookie. Or localstorage.

Comment: @j08691 could you give me the code or any links ..it would be helpfull..Thanx'

Comment: Can you explain more about wht you mean by save? depending on how persistant you need the save the answers will be different

Comment: @atmd see i just want to save those value in a cookie or in localstorage..supose if i clicked the male and click save ..i just want to see the selected check near male..

Comment: Use [localStorage](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Web_Storage_API).

Comment: so do you want the male to still be selected if you refresh the page, came back later, came back a week later etc?

Answer (score 0):

So as most comments point toward you using localStorage, here we go:

to store a value

```
 localStorage.setItem(key, value); 
 // i.e.  localStorage.setItem("name", "bob" );
```

To get the value back you'd do

```
localStorage.getItem(key)
// i.e. localStorage.getItem('name');
```

so:

```
<input id="male" type="radio" name="sex" value="male">Male
<input id="female" type="radio" name="sex" value="female">Female



if(document.getElementById('male').checked){
    localStorage.setItem('sex', 'male');
}
if(document.getElementById('female').checked){
    localStorage.setItem('sex', 'female');
}


// getting the value
if(localStorage.getItem('sex')){
    // if localStorage.getItem('sex') == male, set the male checkbox
    // female if not
}
```

Comment: could you edit the answer with my concept ??..i have done if(value is checked) { localstorage.getItem(value); } but i cant get the radio buton checked

Comment: i did it ..but the check option is gone when the page is refreshed

Comment: At no point did you mention anything about page refreshing. so I assume you want to set the correct checkbox on refresh from the saved value?. So you know how to get a value from localStorage now so the rest should be stright forward

Comment: yeah exacly i just want to set the correct checkbox on refresh from the saved value ..so i have tried `localStorage.getItem()` but it didnt worked out

Comment: what do you mean 'didnt work out' getItem gives a null if the key/value doesn't exist, as per my updated answer. Maybe you should update your code if you've changed it dramatically

Comment: i have did this ..but it didnt gave me an error and the checkbox is gone when page is refreshed

Answer (score 0):

You could use cookies for this. Here is a general example:

```
<body onload="pageLoad()">
    <form action="" id="avi">
        <input type="radio" name="sex" value="male">Male<br>
        <input type="radio" name="sex" value="female">Female
    </form>
    <br></br>

    <button type="button" id="bae" onclick="save()">save me   </button>

    <script>
        var pageLoad = function () {
            var savedValue = document.cookie.replace(/(?:(?:^|.*;\s*)sex\s*\=\s*([^;]*).*$)|^.*$/, "$1");

            if (savedValue === 'male') {
                document.querySelector('#avi input[type="radio"][value="male"]').checked = true;
            }
            else if (savedValue === 'female') {
                document.querySelector('#avi input[type="radio"][value="female"]').checked = true;
            }
        };

        var save = function () {
            var m = document.querySelector('#avi input[type="radio"]:checked');
            if (m)
                document.cookie = "sex=" + m.value;
        }
    </script>
</body>
```

Some other things to note:

- Your original code was not actually selecting the checked radio value
  in the click handler. You were grabbing the id of the form instead of
  the currently selected radio.
- You can just have a handler on the button in the markup instead of
  adding the handler in javascript. This is much easier with the way
  you are coding this. If you were using jQuery, I would say forgo the 
  handler in markup and replace it with a handler assignment in a ready
  block.

Comment: it says `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'value' of null`

Answer (score 0):

Your radiobuttons are part of a form, forms are sent to the server, and the refresh occurs when it comes back. Because of this, you will require a server-side language to know what radiobutton was checked in the client-side, like PHP, and you don't need to store anything in the database. Here's the code:

CLIENT SIDE : MYWEBPAGE.PHP

```
<html>
  <head>
  </head>
  <body>
<?php
// GET FROM SERVER WHAT RADIOBUTTON WAS CHECKED (IN ANY).
$chk = $_SESSION["sex_checked"];
if ( strcmp( $chk,"male" ) == 0 )
     $male = "checked";
 else $male = "";
if ( strcmp( $chk,"female" ) == 0 )
     $female = "checked";
else $female = "";   
?>
    <form action="myscript.php" method="post">
      <input type="radio" name="sex" value="male" <?php echo male; ?> />Male
      <input type="radio" name="sex" value="female"<?php echo female; ?> />Female
      <input type="submit" value="Save me" /> 
    </form >
  </body >
</html>
```

SERVERSIDE : MYSCRIPT.PHP

```
<?php
$_SESSION["sex_checked"] = $_POST["sex"]; // SAVE CHECKED RADIOBUTTON.
header( "Location: mywebpage.php" ); // RETURN TO WEB PAGE (REFRESH).
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to set AND get the value

```js
    function setCookie(name, value, days) { // from http://www.quirksmode.org/js/cookies.html
        if (days) {
            var date = new Date();
            date.setTime(date.getTime() + (days * 24 * 60 * 60 * 1000));
            var expires = "; expires=" + date.toGMTString();
        } else var expires = "";
        document.cookie = name + "=" + value + expires + "; path=/";
    }
    
    function getCookie(name) {
        var nameEQ = name + "=";
        var ca = document.cookie.split(';');
        for (var i = 0; i < ca.length; i++) {
            var c = ca[i];
            while (c.charAt(0) == ' ') c = c.substring(1, c.length);
            if (c.indexOf(nameEQ) == 0) return c.substring(nameEQ.length, c.length);
        }
        return null;
    }
    
    window.onload = function () {
        var gender = getCookie('samplecookie');
        if (gender) {
            if (gender=="male") document.getElementsByName('sex')[0].click(); // or .checked=true; 
            else if (gender=="female") document.getElementsByName('sex')[1].click();
        }
        document.getElementById('bae').onclick = function () {
            var m = document.getElementsByName('sex')[0];
            var f = document.getElementsByName('sex')[1];
            if (m.checked) {
                setCookie('samplecookie', m.value, 30);
            } else if (f.checked) {
                setCookie('samplecookie', f.value, 30);
            }
        }
    }
```

```html
<form action="" id="avi">
<input type="radio" name="sex" value="male">Male<br>
<input type="radio" name="sex" value="female">Female
</form>
<br></br>

<button type="button"  id="bae">save me   </button>
```