# Storing the clicked value in radio buttonswith cookies

Tags: javascript, html

Hey guys am new to js actually..I have two radio buttons and a save button..The code i have done

```
    <input id="male" type="radio" name="sex" id="male" value="male">Male
<input id="female" type="radio" name="sex" id="female" value="female">Female
<button id="buttons">Save me </button>

<script>

function setCookie(cname,cvalue,exdays) {
var d = new Date();
d.setTime(d.getTime() + (exdays*24*60*60*1000));
var expires = "expires=" + d.toGMTString();
document.cookie = cname+"="+cvalue+"; "+expires;
}


var c = document.getElementById('buttons');
c.onclick = function() {
var c = document.getElementById('male');
var m = document.getElementById('female');

if(c.checked == 'true') {
setCookie('samplecookie', c.value, 30 );
} else if(n.checked == 'true') {
setCookie('anothersamplecookie', n.value, 30);
}

}
</script>
```

## What should i need to do.

Suppose i clicked on the female radio button and click the save button the value needs to be stored and the value will remain be checked even the page is refreshed..The above code didnt works for me ..The radio  button gets unchecked when the page is refreshed..

I have asked a similar qus [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27924961/keep-the-selected-option-saved-within-js/27926172#27926172).But it didnt helped me ..I have heard this can be done with localstorage too..But i dont reall know how to.

Hope you guys  would help me with the right code and will be really appreciated..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to set AND get the cookie.

[**FIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/mplungjan/9exn05kn/)

```
function setCookie(name, value, days) { // from http://www.quirksmode.org/js/cookies.html
    if (days) {
        var date = new Date();
        date.setTime(date.getTime() + (days * 24 * 60 * 60 * 1000));
        var expires = "; expires=" + date.toGMTString();
    } else var expires = "";
    document.cookie = name + "=" + value + expires + "; path=/";
}

function getCookie(name) {
    var nameEQ = name + "=";
    var ca = document.cookie.split(';');
    for (var i = 0; i < ca.length; i++) {
        var c = ca[i];
        while (c.charAt(0) == ' ') c = c.substring(1, c.length);
        if (c.indexOf(nameEQ) == 0) return c.substring(nameEQ.length, c.length);
    }
    return null;
}

window.onload = function () {
    var gender = getCookie('samplecookie');
    if (gender) {
        if (gender=="male") document.getElementById('male').click(); // or .checked=true; 
        else if (gender=="female") document.getElementById('female').click();
    }
    document.getElementById('buttons').onclick = function () {
        var m = document.getElementById('male');
        var f = document.getElementById('female');
        if (m.checked) {
            setCookie('samplecookie', m.value, 30);
        } else if (f.checked) {
            setCookie('samplecookie', f.value, 30);
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: Great. I updated the other one with getElementsByName in case you needed it

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if this is something you'd want. But a thing that comes up to mind is the HTML5 Web Storage functionality.With that feature you can store data on the computer of the user.

So whenever a user changes an input field you can create a javascript call that stores the value into the localstorage:

```
   localStorage.setItem(“inputName”, “value”);
```

Then when you load the page, you see if any of these values are stored and then fill them in.

Comment: See i have used the same thing localStorage.setItem('female', c.value) but it didnt give any sucess..can you edit ur ans with my example code ..it would be helpful